# Visual Database Design Delphi VCL components?

Tags: database, delphi

I'm looking for a Delphi VCL component that allows my customers to visually create a database, that is, tables, fields, indexes, etc. Something like this: http://www.devart.com/blogs/dbforge/?p=136#more-136, but available as a third-party component to be embedded into an application. Do you know of something like this? I'm not looking for visual query builders, but database design components.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by looking into [ESS Model](http://essmodel.sourceforge.net/index.html) source code: ess model is a free & open source UML desing and UML reversing tool wich export model data to [XMI-format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange). Once your model generated, you could take it on from there and generate your SQL scripts.

Download : http://essmodel.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/essmodel/essmodel/ 
Source Code : http://essmodel.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/essmodel/essmodel/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the TDatabaseSchema component in Context Software's Database Extensions component set may be close to what you're looking for:

[Context Database Extensions](http://www.contextsoft.com/products/ctxdbext/)

Or maybe you would want/need to combine it with their end-user "Database Designer" product, which can be registered as the component editor for TDatabaseSchema. ( [Database Designer](http://www.contextsoft.com/products/dbdesign/) )  The author would be happy to clarify if you asked, I'm sure.